# How to divide array into small arrays?

Tags: php

I have an array with 3200 values. A user chooses a number (let's say 50). I want to divide the big array into smaller arrays, each of them containing 50 values (the last one containing the remainder).

How would you do that?

Comment: why do you want to split it in smaller chunks?

Comment: Don't forget that php.net is a great resource for determining what built-in functions PHP has. http://ca.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

e.g.

```
 $arrays = array_chunk($my_big_array, 50);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
array array_chunk ( array $input , int $size [, bool $preserve_keys = false ] )
```

Check this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how you want to do it [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) might be a good place to start.